# kafka electing new leader after 2/3 is down

Tags: apache-kafka, scale, partitioning, kafka-topic

2 of my 3 Kafka cluster is down with replica_factor=2ץ
I don't care about the DATA, I just want to save my Kafka and reuse it's topics.
I test one of my topic who has 4 partitions,

I added unclean.leader.election.enable=true
to the server.conf
but only the partitions who have replica on this node changes the leader and the others changed to -1

```
topic:stats      PartitionCount:4         ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:

   Topic: stats    Partition: 0    Leader: -1      Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
   Topic: stats    Partition: 1    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
   Topic: stats    Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 2
   Topic: stats    Partition: 3    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
```

what should I do to change the partition 0 leader to 2 even if it means to lose the data?